# Installing Python Package over offline server using PIP install returning errors in all trials

Tags: python, pip

First trial

```
!pip install pysftyp -e L:\Python_New_Packages\pysftp-0.2.9
```

error

Obtaining file:///L:/Python_New_Packages/pysftp-0.2.9

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysftyp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysftyp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysftyp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysftyp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysftyp/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysftyp (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysftyp

Comment: That could be related to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630164/3986141

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pysftyp` is trying to install `pysftyp` from https://pypi.org/project/pysftyp/ and failed as the host is offline.

Perhaps you need

```
!pip install --no-index -e L:\Python_New_Packages\pysftp-0.2.9
```

Comment: ERROR: --no-index is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+).

Comment: above mentioned error was happened and the server is offline and this path is a path for library which downloaded from online server

Comment: Let's try the other way: `!pip install --no-index -e L:\Python_New_Packages\pysftp-0.2.9`